# Finding the difference between two times of day

Tags: c++

Input prompt asks for a starting time, and then a duration time where it returns two times: one time where they are added, and one where they are subtracted. I've gotten the basics of them, but when I try and do it for certain times (ex: 1:18 and 10:39) I get a negative error:

```
    X Input of 1:18 10:39 : expected [11:57, 2:39] but found [11:57, -9:-21]
```

Here's the code that does the calculations:

```
int timeHours, timeMinutes, durHours, durMinutes;
cout << "    Time: ";
cin >> timeHours;
cin.get();
cin >> timeMinutes;

cout << "    Duration: ";
cin >> durHours;
cin.get();
cin >> durMinutes;

int time, duration, after, before, afterHours, afterMinutes, beforeHours, beforeMinutes;
const int MINUTES_IN_DAY = 60 * 24;
time = (timeHours * 60) + timeMinutes;
duration = (durHours * 60) + durMinutes;
after = time + duration;
before = time - duration;
afterHours = after / 60 % 12;
afterMinutes = after % 60;
beforeHours = before / 60;
beforeMinutes = before % 60;

cout << endl;
cout << durHours << ":" << setfill('0') << setw(2) << durMinutes << " hours after, and before, "
    << timeHours << ":" << timeMinutes << " is [" << afterHours << ":" << setw(2) << afterMinutes << ", "
    << beforeHours << ":" << setw(2) << beforeMinutes << "]" << endl;
```

The failed test above shows that the sum (1:18 + 10:39) works but the difference (1:18 - 10:39) does not work. It gives me "-9:-21" which should be able to be fixed by adding 24 hours, which is even what my assignment suggests: "This is easily done by adding a day (or two or three) to before when calculating the difference" but when I add 1440 (60 * 24) to the "before" initialization:

```
before = (time - duration) + MINUTES_IN_DAY;
```

and convert back from minutes to normal time I get 14:39, which is 2:39, but in 24 hour form, not 12 (incidentally it also makes all the other tests which were passing now failing). I think there's some hint when it says "by adding a day (or two or three) since obviously 1440 is different from 1440*2 or *3, but I'm not seeing it and I have to be missing something obvious. I know I'll have to fix it for midnight as well but I'll change that later. If anyone knows what I'm trying to explain, I'd really appreciate it

Comment: So determine if this is a math issue, or a programming issue.  If it is a math issue, you need to work that out before you write any code.  Once you work that out, then you take that and create a program.  Too many new programmers want to jump and write the program right away without taking a step back and working out the math, logic, etc. on paper first.

Comment: What did you observe when stepping through your code with the debugger line by line?

Comment: Also, you could do yourself a big favor by printing out those intermediate values, or as suggested, use a debugger to debug your code.  It seems you're guessing what those values are and just trying different things until you get lucky and have the program work.  That's not the way you're supposed to develop a program.

Answer (score 0):

( like you suggested to add MINUTES_IN_DAY) to solve the negative values problem you can use the %MINUTES_IN_DAY to avoid the overflow caused by adding  MINUTES_IN_DAY to a positive value

```
 before = ((time - duration)+MINUTES_IN_DAY)%MINUTES_IN_DAY;
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when working with times/dates it's easier to make yourself a function to convert a human-readable date to milliseconds or seconds (and vice versa) and build up from that base. In your case, you'll just add/subtract the two time-marks in seconds for example:

```
long long time = toSec(timeHours, timeMinutes, timeSeconds);
long long duration = toSec(durHours, durMinutes, durSeconds);

string after = toDate(time + duration);//somethig like 12:34:00 (hh:mm:ss)
string before = toDate(time - duration);
```

however, putting effort in making such conversion functions would be an overcomplication if all you use them for is a one-time calculation.